# USACO help, my program should be working but throwing errors

Tags: python-3.x

Doing USACO US OPEN bronze problem, and I have all my code, and it gives me the correct answer no matter what version i give it. Its called Bucket Brigade in case anyone would want to try.

this is a 10x10 graph
..........
..........
..........
..B.......
..........
.....R....
..........
..........
.....L....
..........

A fire has broken out on the farm, and the cows are rushing to try and put it out!
The farm is described by a 10×10 grid of characters like this:

..........
..........
..........
..B.......
..........
.....R....
..........
..........
.....L....
..........
The character 'B' represents the barn, which has just caught on fire. The 'L' character represents a lake, and 'R' represents the location of a large rock.

The cows want to form a "bucket brigade" by placing themselves along a path between the lake and the barn so that they can pass buckets of water along the path to help extinguish the fire. A bucket can move between cows if they are immediately adjacent in the north, south, east, or west directions. The same is true for a cow next to the lake --- the cow can only extract a bucket of water from the lake if she is immediately adjacent to the lake. Similarly, a cow can only throw a bucket of water on the barn if she is immediately adjacent to the barn.

Please help determine the minimum number of '.' squares that should be occupied by cows to form a successful bucket brigade.

A cow cannot be placed on the square containing the large rock, and the barn and lake are guaranteed not to be immediately adjacent to each-other.

INPUT FORMAT (file buckets.in):
The input file contains 10 rows each with 10 characters, describing the layout of the farm.
OUTPUT FORMAT (file buckets.out):
Output a single integer giving the minimum number of cows needed to form a viable bucket brigade.
SAMPLE INPUT:
..........
..........
..........
..B.......
..........
.....R....
..........
..........
.....L....
..........
SAMPLE OUTPUT:
7

for the first test which is the sample, i get it correct, however the other 7 show that I have an incorrect output. Here is my code

```
'''
# 57 % 25 is mod
fin = open ('buckets.in', 'r')
fout = open('buckets.out', 'w')

#COMETQ \n
inp = fin.read().splitlines()
first = inp[0]
second = inp[1]
third = inp[2]
fourth = inp[3]
fifth = inp[4]
sixth = inp[5]
seventh = inp[6]
eighth = inp[7]
ninth = inp[8]
tenth = inp[9]
Barny = 0

if first.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 0
if second.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 1 
if third.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 2 
if fourth.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 3
if fifth.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 4
if sixth.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 5
if seventh.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 6
if eighth.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 7
if ninth.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 8
if tenth.find("B") >= 0:
    Barny = 9



Barnx = inp[Barny].find("B")
if first.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 0
if second.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 1
if third.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 2
if fourth.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 3
if fifth.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 4
if sixth.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 5
if seventh.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 6
if eighth.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 7
if ninth.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 8
if tenth.find("L") >= 0:
    Lakey = 9

Lakex = inp[Lakey].find("L")

if first.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 0
if second.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 1
if third.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 2
if fourth.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 3
if fifth.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 4
if sixth.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 5
if seventh.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 6
if eighth.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 7
if ninth.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 8
if tenth.find("R") >= 0:
    Rocky = 9

Rockx = inp[Rocky].find("R")



Ansx = Lakex - Barnx
Ansy = Lakey - Barny


if Ansx == 0:
  Final = ((Ansy*Ansy)/Ansy)+2
elif Ansy == 0:
  Final = ((Ansx*Ansx)/Ansx)+2
else:
  Final = ((Ansx*Ansx)/Ansx)+((Ansy*Ansy)/Ansy)

Finalout = int(Final)

print(Finalout-1)
fout.write(str(Finalout-1))
fout.close()
'''
```

so buckets.in is the 10x10 graph
and buckets.out should be 7, but they test 8 different versions like lake and barn being located in other places.

How would I fix my code? unfortunatly my 5 hours is up so I can't do anymore

thanks to anyone that helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a competition problem, and you are not supposed to receive help or post solutions online when it comes to things of this nature. Please discuss these problems after the contests are over to ensure a fair playing field.